# Fatal error while deploying project on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, version, cpanel

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:914 Stack trace: #0 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(914): ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(795): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(933): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true) #3 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(731): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array) #4 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(918): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array) #5 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1456): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config') #6 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(546): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config') #7 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(597): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver() #8 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(124): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL) #9 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(667): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver() #10 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(274): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Call to undefin...', Array) #11 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(491): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error)) #12 /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->reportException(Object(Error)) #13 /home/icyari/public_html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #14 {main} Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [config] does not exist. in /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:916 Stack /home/icyari/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 916

```
composer update
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config: clear
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Should there not be a space between `config:` and `clear` in your last command?

Comment: Try: Go to cd bootstrap/cache/ and then "rm -rf *.php" After that run "composer dump-autoload". It will solve your problem.

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy my laravel 10 project to cpanel @BentheCoder

Comment: Why don't you put that in your question?